# Python Selenium gets detected when using a user agent but doesn't when not using one

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I've made an autobuy bot for Amazon in Python using Selenium. It's working fine except that Amazon doesn't show some important things for my purpose while on Computer, but it does on mobile, so I added a user agent (which was not needed before since it only opens Amazon about 2 times a day), to make Amazon show a mobile version of the website. I've always had options to disable the navigator.webdriver flag and automation controlled, etc, but I haven't had a user agent before making it into a mobile version since I didn't get blocked before adding it. However, now after adding the user agent, such as "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; SM-G998B) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36", I'm now getting detected. I'm using cookies to login to make it faster. I'm able to go onto their website, but when ~80-90% of the time, I have to put in my password which would make the bot slower and I suppose I would have to accept an email aswell.
I would guess that I'm getting detected since I don't need to input my password on my normal browser(chrome), but I do when using chromedriver. I've gone as far as modifying the source code of chromedriver to see if that helps.
I start getting the pages saying that I need to input my password after buying a product about one time, supporting my thought that I'm getting detected.
How can I go about making it undetected? Or is there any other libraries that are better than Selenium? To clarify, I'm currently using cookies to login to my account with Selenium.
If there are no ways that you can think of that would help, is it possible to make the website a mobile version without changing the user agent? (In this case, I do not want the bot to be slower. The time matters a lot in my case)
Thank you!

Comment: It depends on which website are you using, but on some of them you can just decrease the resolutin of the browser, and it automatically switches to the mobile version.

Comment: Amazon only seems to change it when using User agents from a mobile. Using Chrome's DevTools with their device emulation, it displays the mobile version when using User agents but not when only using a smaller viewport